# Can I import or sync Apple/iCloud's Reminders into Google Inbox reminders?

Tags: synchronization, reminder, inbox-by-gmail, icloud

I'd like to try to switch from iCloud's Reminders to Google Inbox ones.

Can I automatically sync them?

If I can't, can I at least one-way import them?

My devices are a Mac running 10.10 and an Android running 4.4.4.